# Text selectability in disabled HTML inputs

Tags: html, usability, html-input, disabled-control

In our application we use disabled text inputs quite often. However, they are not user-friendly, because in some browsers (Chrome, Firefox, but not e.g. IE) you cannot select text inside with the mouse. This makes it very difficult to copy text that you are not allowed to edit.

It seems that in HTML it would be preferrable to use `readonly` flag rather than `disabled` in such cases. However, we cannot really do that easily, because it changes what is submitted to the server, and so the whole application would need to be adapted and tested if we wanted to make such a change. In addition, I think it unnecessarily creates another state with unclear semantics for the user.

So, I would prefer to keep the inputs disabled, but make their text selectable in all browsers, if possible. **Question: is it possible to make text selectable, perhaps with some CSS?**

Here is a simple HTML to test with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input value="bla bla bla"/> <!-- selectable -->
    <input value="bla bla bla" disabled="disabled"/> <!-- selectable only in IE -->
    <input value="bla bla bla" readonly="readonly"/> <!-- selectable -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let's go a step back and explain why you need to use inputs in  the first place if you don't mean them to be used as inputs.

Comment: Because, for example, they are real editable inputs for one user, but not for another, depending on permissions. Moreover, you can have permissions for some inputs on the page, but not the others. And finally, sometimes this can be dynamic, with e.g. checkbox controlling whether an input is disabled or not.

Comment: OK. In that case, sorry, I don't have any solutions. I tried with `contenteditable`, but that doesn't work on inputs (since they don't have content) and I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: IE and Chrome works in your (second) example. Seems to be a firefox-only issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195361
Even -moz-user-select: text; is not recognized by Firefox but should be in my opinion.
If you can't change anything, may hiding this field completely is the better solution anyway.

Comment: Looks like Chrome was like this for only one version, but quickly reverted the change. But in the end we found out that using `readonly` was not as hard as it seemed in our application, since we have an intermediate presentation layer above HTML. So we change `disabled` to `readonly` when generating final HTML in this custom layer. Now for us it's also not a problem in Firefox, but in any case I consider its behavior stupid.

Comment: Not working on Microsoft Edge for me.............